# Evaluating the integral for a random walk

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-walk, integer-lattices, elliptic-integrals

Could someone please evaluate the integral:
$$P(\vec{l};z)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\text{exp}(-i(l_{1}k_{1}+l_{2}k_{2})d{k_{1}}d{k_{2}}}{1-z^2\lambda(\vec{k})}$$
$\vec{l}$ is the direction variable.
The integral is a representative of a random walk on the honeycomb lattice.

$$\lambda(k)=\frac{1}{9}[1+(2\cos(k_{1}))^2+4\cos(k_{1})\cos(k_{2})]$$

$k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ are the Fourier variables and $z$ is the $z$ transform/generating function variable.

**Edit source for the integral:** https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.1435.pdf

**Edit**: I made some progress in the equation post modifying the integral to account for the basis vectors,
We can take $\exp(-ik_1)=t_1$ and similarly for $k_{2}$, then we can write the cosine terms in terms of $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ which we assume are complex valued and hence we can evaluate it using contour integrals?
[image: Progress on Edit]

**Edit2**Another approach that I am exploring is expanding the terms-
[image: Another approach]

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please show your efforts by adding more context. What have you tried/thought so far?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.1435.pdf
Using this paper I was trying to solve the integral but then on doing some more research:https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323584728_Analytic_properties_for_the_honeycomb_lattice_Green_function_at_the_origin
This paper presents a method where they modify the function to evaluate the integral on page 4, what I was keen to understand was is this the solution to my integral problem.
Please do note very new to elliptic integrals and hence asked this question, also would need to evaluate any further intergrals of such nature further in my work!

Comment: I've been looking into the draft and I have a minor question: If the coefficient of $z^n$ in $P(0,z)$ is the probability of return to the origin after exactly $n$ steps, then $P(0,1)$ is the probability of return to the origin at some point, right? But then it says $1-1/P(0,1)$ is the probability of return to the origin?

Comment: So 1 is subtracted because P(0,1) is the probability that after n steps it returns to the origin.
.Right so I don't need the equation for P(0,z) but the equation for P(l,z) instead!

Comment: @Manan need help in evaluating the integral having taken multiple approaches to evaluate as a legendre series :(

Comment: @Ameya This question is way beyond my mathematical expertise; however, I'll place a bounty on this problem if it doesn't draw any answer in a reasonable time.

Comment: @Manan have made some changes to the integral.